# sum over rows split between two columns

Tags: sum, sas, datastep

my data looks like this and I cant figure out how to obtain the column "want". I've tried various combinations of retain, lag and sum functions with no success unfortunately.

```
month   quantity1   quantity2   want
1       a           x           x+sum(b to l)
2       b           y           sum(x to y)+sum(c to l)
3       c           z           sum(x to z)+sum(d to l)
4       d       
5       e       
6       f       
7       g       
8       h       
9       i       
10      j       
11      k       
12      l
```

Thank you for any help on this matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convenient to sum quantity1 and then store value to macro variable. Use superfluous' data example:

```
proc sql;
   select sum(qty1) into:sum_qty1 from temp;
quit;

data want;
   set temp;
   value1+qty1;
   value2+qty2;
   want=value2+&sum_qty1-value1;
   if missing(qty2) then want=.;
   drop value:;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this in one step, but the following produces the desired result in two. The first step is to calculate the sum of the relevant `quantity1` values, and the second is to add them to the sum of the relevant `quantity2` values:

```
 data temp;
    input month qty1 qty2;
    datalines;
        1 1 100
        2 1 100
        3 1 100
        4 1 .
        5 1 .
        6 1 .
        7 1 .
        8 1 .
        9 1 .
        10 1 .
        11 1 .
        12 1 .
    ;
run;

proc sql;
    create table qty1_sums as select distinct
        a.*, sum(b.qty1) as qty1_sums
        from temp as a
        left join temp as b
        on a.month < b.month
        group by a.month;

    create table want as select distinct
        a.*,
        case when not missing(a.qty2) then sum(a.qty1_sums, sum(b.qty2)) end as want
        from qty1_sums as a
        left join temp as b
        on a.month >= b.month
        group by a.month;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a 'rolling 12 months sum'.  If so, much easier to do with a different data structure (not 2 variables, but 24 rows 1 variable); then you have all of the ETS tools, or a simple process in either SQL or SAS data step.

If you can't/won't restructure your data, then you can do this by loading the data into temporary arrays (or hash table but arrays are simpler for a novice).  That gives you access to the whole thing right up front.  Example:

```
data have;
  do month = 1 to 12;
    q_2014 = rand('Uniform')*10+500+month*5;
    q_2015 = rand('Uniform')*10+550+month*5;
    output;
  end;
run;

data want;
  array q2014[12] _temporary_;       *temporary array to hold data;
  array q2015[12] _temporary_;
  if _n_=1 then do;                  *load data into temporary arrays;
    do _n = 1 to n_data;
      set have point=_n nobs=n_data;
      q2014[_n] = q_2014;
      q2015[_n] = q_2015;
    end;
  end;
  set have;
  do _i = 1 to _n_;                          *grab the this_year data;
    q_rolling12 = sum(q_rolling12,q2015[_i]);
  end;
  do _j = _n_+1 to n_data;
    q_rolling12 = sum(q_rolling12,q2014[_j]);*grab the last_year data;
  end;
run;
```